# What is the most popular/standard way to customize order of context menus in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pasting code snippet from : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/mainwindows-menus.html

```
void MainWindow::createActions()
{
newAct = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);
newAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::New);
newAct->setStatusTip(tr("Create a new file"));
connect(newAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));

openAct = new QAction(tr("&Open..."), this);
openAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Open);
openAct->setStatusTip(tr("Open an existing file"));
connect(openAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(open()));

saveAct = new QAction(tr("&Save"), this);
saveAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Save);
saveAct->setStatusTip(tr("Save the document to disk"));
connect(saveAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(save()));
}
```

Now I want to give user an option to customize the order of "menu addition", i.e. I want this sequence New, Open and Save to be dynamically decided at run time. 
How can I achieve this in QT?
What is the standard way to make menus customize-able?

Comment: Do you need the API for arranging menu items, or what?

Comment: Create your own menu controller.

Comment: I'm trying to arrange these menu items according to an order of names of the menu passed to me by some xml file( where I save orders).
I tried to make cases for each individual items and then using switch-case. I don't think its a very good method cause if someone wants to add new menu items then he has to put extra effort for making cases and all.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Any pointers to that?

Comment: Currently I'm writing my own. But it's not open-source.